# C - Can't add elements to a char array

Tags: c, arrays

```
void initializeEncryptArray(char key[], char encrypt[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 90;

    char *endkey = removeDuplicates(key);
    printf("%s\n", endkey);

    while((int)endkey[i] != 0){
        encrypt[i] = endkey[i];
        i++;
    }

    while(j >= 65){
        if (targetFound(encrypt, i, (char)j) != 0){
            encrypt[i] = (char)j;
            i++;
        }
        j--;
    }
    printf("Finished encryption.\n");
    printf("%c\n", encrypt[0]);
}
```

So here's my code, and I'm trying to take characters in the key, remove all duplicates (which works), and then add them to a final `encrypt` char array. Then add the rest of the alphabet in reverse order to the same array. However, when I print the first character in the array, it's empty. `endkey` is filled, and it gets to the end, but the actual `encrypt` array is empty. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so what is the content of `encrypt[0]` ?

Comment: The first character in the char array

Comment: I mean, what is the value of it , and besides how do you know that the array is empty ?

Comment: Based on the input I'm feeding it, it should be 'R,' but when I print it, it's just blank space.

Comment: what about remaining chars in `encrypt` ?

Comment: all empty unfortunately

Comment: Maybe you're overflowing a buffer

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile and it calls other 'home grown' functions, which are not part of the posted code.    When asking a question about a runtime problem, the posted code should be complete, cleanly compile, be small, and still exhibit the problem.  The posted code fails on al these particulars.   Please edit, other wise we can only guess as we cannot actually run/debug the code

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  65, 90  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: NOTE: the first `while()` loop will result in `i` containing the index to the NUL string terminator byte.   The second `while()` loop starts with`i` containing that same index, then increments that index.   ?is the buffer 'encrypt[] long enough to hold everything?

Comment: the second `while()` loop would be better written as: `for( int j=90; j>=65; j-- )`

Comment: the second `while()` loop fails to re-terminate the char string (via appending a NUL byte. to the char array `encrypt[]`

Comment: the second `while()` loop will probably never make any changes to the `encrypt[]` array.

Comment: exactly what does the array pointed to by `endkey` contain?   If the first char is a NUL, then `encrypt[]` array will contain nothing.

Comment: to help us,  post the functions: `removeDuplicatios()` and `targetFound()`

Comment: this line: while((int)endkey[i] != 0) would be much better written as: `while( endkey[i] );